# Does Sql Query Notification work for clr stored procedures?

Tags: stored-procedures, caching, clr

Trying to set up caching on our datasets - we're using clr stored procedures -
The database doesn't seem to notify the application of data changes

Comment: Any clues as to what you are trying to do? Is this MSSQL 2005 or MSSQL 2008? Is this Express or one of the full versions? Are you implementing your notifications by hand (SqlNotificationRequest) or using the high level class (SqlDependency)?

No details means fewer and lower quality answers.

Comment: MSSQL 2005. We're using SqlDependency class in an ASP.NET application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much testing, the answer seems to be no... it doesn't seem to work for CLR stored procedures.